# bash script, printing multiple lines matching to a specific patern

Tags: regex, bash, sed, multiline

I have a log file and I'm making a script to do some actions. An action is to print a specific area of the log.

```
 03:19:13.4 End summary update for ads.doc.ordered.OrderDetailSummary
 03:19:13.4 Begin summary update for ads.doc.inventory.InventoryItemSummary
 03:19:33.9 CronServer:: DailyJob ads.tools.UpdateSummaries@17c5d6cf failed with exception
  ads.util.AppError: Cannot create UnitName from keys: Each
  ads.util.AppError: Cannot create UnitName from keys: Each
  .....
  .....
  .....
  .....
 03:46:42.5 Periodic support request failed: ads.support.SupportException: Error opening socket: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
 06:31:36.1 Upload failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:/tmp/cygwin1.dll (No such file or directory)
 08:01:08.0 connect from /172.22.3.28
```

OR

```
06:14:27.9 starting web server
06:14:33.3 Initializing Spring framework Logs
Oct 18, 2013 6:14:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start
INFO: Starting tomcat server
Oct 18, 2013 6:14:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
Oct 18, 2013 6:14:35 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig defaultWebConfig
INFO: No default web.xml
Oct 18, 2013 6:14:38 AM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doLoad
SEVERE: IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: ads.doc.backoffice.StoreInfos
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: ads.doc.backoffice.StoreInfos
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1354)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
......
......
......
......

    at ads.tools.AppServerMain.main(AppServerMain.java:83)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: ads.doc.backoffice.StoreInfos
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/105  config=null
06:14:48.6 Starting exporter server
06:14:48.6 starting cron server
```

I want to print the block that contains the word exception. From a time stamp to the next time stamp

e.g1

```
03:19:33.9 CronServer:: DailyJob ads.tools.UpdateSummaries@17c5d6cf failed with exception ads.util.AppError: Cannot create UnitName from keys: Each
ads.util.AppError: Cannot create UnitName from keys: Each
.....
.....
.....
.....
```

and the next timestamp if it's easier.

OR

e.g2

```
06:14:33.3 Initializing Spring framework Logs
......
......
......

java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: ads.doc.backoffice.StoreInfos
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1354)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
......
......
......
......

    at ads.tools.AppServerMain.main(AppServerMain.java:83)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: ads.doc.backoffice.StoreInfos
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/105  config=null
06:14:48.6 Starting exporter server
```

Is there a way to do this with sed? Or any other idea because I really got confused.

As I know sed process a single line at a time.

Thought to search if a line starts with this pattern

```
^[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]
```

and then there is a match with the exception word and after the next line matches again the expression to print all this block.

Comment: "grep -n -i exception yourfile" reports the line number where the word exception has been found, seems to be a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

The critical lines seem not to begin with a date, so you could search for your error condition or lines not beginning with a date like this:

```
egrep -i "exception|^\s" yourlog
```

where the "\s" is a space.

Or alternatively, lines not beginning with a digit:

```
egrep -i "exception|^[^0-9]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

```
sed '/exception/,/^[0-9][0-9]/!d' filename
```

For your input, it'd return:

```
03:19:33.9 CronServer:: DailyJob ads.tools.UpdateSummaries@17c5d6cf failed with exception
ads.util.AppError: Cannot create UnitName from keys: Each
ads.util.AppError: Cannot create UnitName from keys: Each
.....
.....
.....
.....
03:46:42.5 Periodic support request failed: ads.support.SupportException: Error opening socket: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

---

**EDIT**: For your updated question, the following might work for you:

```
sed -n -e :t -e '/^[0-9]/,/^[0-9]/{/^[0-9]/!{$!{N;bt}};/[Ex]xception/p;}' inputfile
```

Comment: This worked, but in my log file the word exception sometimes is one,two or many line after the start of the timestamp, so if begin with exception i'm missing those 2-3 lines before the line with the matching word. Is it possible to mach to sed like this, but the first will have for begin the expression ^[0-9][0-9] for end a space and the the patern you gave, so it will take from one timestamp to the next and anything includes the word expression between.

Comment: @CTs See the edit above.  Your logs don't seem to be consistent; at times those start with a timestamp and on other times with a date.

Comment: Thanks for your help, can you explain me the edit version? inside the braces what is happening? At the start why we have twice -e? Every timestamp begins with the specific pattern 00:00:00.0 and inside the timpestamp may be other times with date. With the edit version of your answer I lost again some lines at the begining and print extra lines at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
 perl -n -e 'if ( $_ =~ /^ \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d/ ) { $print = 0; } if ($print || $_ =~ /exception/) { print "$_"; $print = 1 };
```

Something like that should be the perl alternative.

Use like that `cat file.txt | perl ...`

Answer (score 0):

Sed has ranges by patterns: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-29

So you could do something like:

```
 sed -n '/AppError/,/^ *[0-9]\{1,2\}:[0-9]\{1,2\}:[0-9]\{1,2\}\.[0-9]/ p' file.log
```

-n ... to suppress printing unless you print explicitly
You can refine the start pattern to your liking.

In your end pattern, you need to escape the curly braces.

Comment: Escape them for `sed`, that is. In `sed`, curly braces are functional tokens for grouping, which you can make use of if you wan to, let's exclude the line matching your end pattern from printing.
http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-35a

Comment: As devnull's answer it's ok but I'm losing some lines before the begin part of the sed because the log is huge and sometimes the word exception it's some lines after the begin of the timestamp.